# Win32 Toolbar Handle

Tags: python, winapi, toolbar, handle

This should be a simple question but I'm new to python and to win32 and can't seem to find an answer to this. I'm using python with the win32gui library and I want to know how do I retrieve the handle to a toolbar in a window.

Say I have notepad.exe open and I want to access the "File" "Edit" etc. buttons in the toolbar, how do I do that and how do I get a handle to the toolbar to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notepad does not have a toolbar.  Notepad has a menu.

You can retrieve the handle of the menu associated with a window using [`GetMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Yea I ended up figuring that out, thank you though! How can I click on a button in the menu?

Comment: @yasman How to click?  Locate the big zero to the left of my post.  Position your mouse pointer over the little arrow above the zero and click your left mouse button.  Repeat for the big tick.  To click a menu item, send the WM_COMMAND message that would be sent if the user clicked the menu item.  If you need more details ask a question.

Comment: Well if you take a look at my reputation you can see that I'm very new on here so I can't rate posts, sorry dude. Ok so I send a WM_COMMAND message but I'm having trouble assigning the value of WPARAM since it has a low and hi word and I don't know how to assign those from python. Can you help me on that?

Comment: In C/C++ you use `MAKEWPARAM(loword, hiword)`.  The `pywin32` module probably implements this, though I haven't checked.

Comment: @yasman Your reputation may be low, but you can accept answer. Finding the value to use for WM_COMMAND is easy with spy++. Do you have a full Visual Studio version? You could also use the GetMenu, GetSubMenu, GetMenuString, GetMenuItemID and others Win32 API to retrieve all the infos for a menu, but it's easier with a message spy like Spy++

Comment: @manuell thanks for the heads up, I'm completely new on here so I'm just learning, now I know. I've gotten over accessing the menu bar and items I can do that fine. Do you think you can help me access the icons in the system tray? I know it's a toolbar and I'm trying to get the buttons on the toolbar but in python it doesn't seem straight forward, any help?

Comment: @yasman I may provide more helpful advice if I know what do you want to do with the systray buttons. Do you want to "click"?

Comment: @manuell yes I want to be able to access them, perform a right click (or possibly a left click) and get the pop up menu then select one of the options in the menu